# Submit button with contingent links

Tags: jquery, html

Ok.  I don't know what I'm doing.  I'm going to go back to helping people find jobs.  I ran everything in the Fiddle and migrated it over to two different editors and everything shows up fine, but nothing happens, no alerts, no onclick to submit.  I tried it on my laptop and two pages showed up one with profilebannerIE on it and the other with the html.  Thanks again.

Old man new to jquery.  We have a form that we would like for folks to fill out and submit.  The form was not difficult to create, but now we would like it to do some special things.  I've researched and tried different things for 3 days and this is my last ditch effort.  Many of your forum ideas are very clever and I'm sure ya'll can get this to work in a flash.  Thanks in advance!

We are trying to get the submit button on the following form to go to "website 1" if seven or more of the radio buttons are clicked "yes".  If there are less than 7 "yes" answers we would like it to go to "website 2".

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 http-equiv="content-type">
 <title>Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center;"><big><span
 style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; background-color: white; color: rgb(0, 0, 153);">Survey</span></big></h1>
<div
 style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial Unicode MS; color: rgb(0, 0, 153); font-weight: bold;"><big>Please
answer the following questions and click the 'Submit' button at the bottom of the page.</big></div>
<form method="post" action="http://www.workintexas.com"
 name="Customer Survey"><br>
Are you currently employed?<br>
  <input name="Employed" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Employed" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have readily available, documents to support your authorization to work in the USA?<br>
  <input name="Documents" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Documents" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have a resume?<br>
  <input name="Resume" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Resume" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have reliable transportation?<br>
  <input name="transportation" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="transportation" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have a high school diploma or equivalent?<br>
  <input name="Diploma" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Diploma" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br> 
Do you have an occupational license, certification, or advanced level of education?<br>
  <input name="Cert" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Cert" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Have you been unemployed longer than 6 months?<br>
  <input name="Unemployed" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Unemployed" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Have you had more than three jobs within the last two years?<br>
  <input name="Jobs" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Jobs" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have appropriate interview clothing?<br>
  <input name="Clothing" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Clothing" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have a criminal background?<br>
  <input name="Background" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Background" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
  <input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"><small><br>
  <br>
  <br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [submit button to contingent pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432769/submit-button-to-contingent-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference, there's a nifty tool called jsFiddle that you can use to give us better code to work with: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

I've made you a quick one, with a solution that should get you started [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9eqRd/1/)

```
var answered_yes = 0;
$("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
        answered_yes++;
    }
});
if (answered_yes >= 7) {
    location.href = "7 or more website.html";
} else {
    location.href = "less than 7 website.html";
}
```

## Full Markup

Here's the markup you can use (with jQuery library included from a CDN), your markup needs a fair bit of work but you've made it clear you're a beginner so I'll throw you a bone.  See if you get anywhere further with this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>Survey</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">
        <big><span style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS; background-color: white; color: rgb(0, 0, 153);">Survey</span></big>
    </h1>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-family: Arial Unicode MS; color: rgb(0, 0, 153); font-weight: bold;">
        <big>Please answer the following questions and click the 'Submit' button at the bottom of the page.</big>
    </div>
    <form method="post" action="http://www.workintexas.com" name="Customer Survey">
        <br>Are you currently employed?<br>
        <input name="Employed" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Employed" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have readily available, documents to support your authorization to work in the USA?<br>
        <input name="Documents" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Documents" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have a resume?<br>
        <input name="Resume" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Resume" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have reliable transportation?<br>
        <input name="transportation" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="transportation" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have a high school diploma or equivalent?<br>
        <input name="Diploma" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Diploma" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have an occupational license, certification, or advanced level of education?<br>
        <input name="Cert" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Cert" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Have you been unemployed longer than 6 months?<br>
        <input name="Unemployed" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Unemployed" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Have you had more than three jobs within the last two years?<br>
        <input name="Jobs" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Jobs" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have appropriate interview clothing?<br>
        <input name="Clothing" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Clothing" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br>Do you have a criminal background?<br>
        <input name="Background" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
        <input name="Background" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
        <br><input name="Submit" value="Submit" type="submit"><small><br>
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var answered_yes = 0;
                $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
                        answered_yes++;
                    }
                });
                if (answered_yes >= 7) {
                    location.href = "7 or more website.html";
                } else {
                    location.href = "less than 7 website.html";
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok.  I'm lost.  It works on the jsfiddle, but when I put it in the editor (kompozer) all that shows up is text.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user2542925 you are including the jQuery library aren't you?  You've tagged jQuery so assumed you were - try including it in your markup `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>` in your `<head>` section.

Comment: Ha!  It works now.  I should have explained further the extent of my inexperience.  Thanks a bunch.  How do I give you credit for helping?

Comment: @user2542925 Good news! Marking the answer as accepted is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following code to get the count of checked radio button, its sample code

HTML

```
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Scaramouche</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Will you do the</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdQueen" /> Fandango</label> <br />

<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Mango</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Kiwi</label> <br />
<label><input type="radio" value="1" name="rdFruit" /> Potato</label> <br />

<button id="test">Run test</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    if($(':radio[name=rdQueen]:checked, :radio[name=rdFruit]:checked').length == 2)
        alert('good to go');
    else
        alert('please choose one from each group');
});
```

Comment: Ok.  I'm lost.  It works on the jsfiddle, but when I put it in the editor (kompozer) all that shows up is text.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It works now.  I didn't even know to include the jquery library.  Gonna stick to helping folks find jobs from now on.  this was fun though.  Thanks again.