# submit button to contingent pages

Tags: jquery, html

Ok.  I don't know what I'm doing.  I'm going to go back to helping people find jobs.  I ran everything in the Fiddle and migrated it over to two different editors and everything shows up fine, but nothing happens, no alerts, no onclick to submit.  I tried it on my laptop and two pages showed up one with profilebannerIE on it and the other with the html.  Thanks again.

Old man new to jquery.  We have a form that we would like for folks to fill out and submit.  The form was not difficult to create, but now we would like it to do some special things.  I've researched and tried different things for 3 days and this is my last ditch effort.  Many of your forum ideas are very clever and I'm sure ya'll can get this to work in a flash.  Thanks in advance!

We are trying to get the submit button on the following form to go to "website 1" if seven or more of the radio buttons are clicked "yes".  If there are less than 7 "yes" answers we would like it to go to "website 2".

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.workintexas.com"
 name="Customer Survey"><br>
Are you currently employed?<br>
  <input name="Employed" value="Yes" type="radio">Yes<br>
  <input name="Employed" value="No" type="radio">No<br>
  <br>
Do you have readily available, documents to support your authorization
```

to work in the USA?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have a resume?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have reliable transportation?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have a high school diploma or equivalent?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have an occupational license, certification, or advanced level
of education?
      Yes
      No
      
    Have you been unemployed longer than 6 months?
      Yes
      No
      
    Have you had more than three jobs within the last two years?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have appropriate interview clothing?
      Yes
      No
      
    Do you have a criminal background?
      Yes
      No

```
$("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answered_yes = 0;
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            answered_yes++;
        }
    });
    if (answered_yes >= 7) {
        alert("7 or more answered yes");
    } else {
        alert("less than 7 answered yes");
    }
});
```

Comment: Someone's flagged the duplicate as a duplicate pointing to this question....my head hurts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `length` property of the checked radio buttons!

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length >=7)
    alert("More than seven OR seven!");
else
    alert("Less than seven!");
```

### [JSFiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AnGPw/)

---

**Final code (with redirections):**

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$("input[type=submit]").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length >= 7)
        window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
    else 
        window.location.href = "http://codereview.stackexchange.com/";
});
```

Comment: quick correct answer :)